# Magento show a specific product on category?

Tags: php, magento, categories, product

Is there any way in Magento to show a specific product (with large image, large description, price and so on) on another category?

**Let me give you an example:**

I have a master category, named **"Apple"**, which **id is 7**. I have to highlight a product from a subcategory which is invisible, to the **"Apple"** category, That sub category name is **"Hero"** and this category **id is 8** - it has only 1 product at time.

Does anyone know how to show this specific product from category id 8? I need price, all the images (large), product description etc.

Really hope you can help me out!

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468059/magento-filter-product-collection-by-multiple-categories/13291759#13291759 check this link. It may help you

Comment: Not a tough task but it touches a number of subjects -- meaning it can be broken down into smaller more concentrated questions.

Comment: Think about it: do you know how to load a category by id? Do you know how to find that category's children categories? Do you know how to load the products from a category? Do you know how to load the products' images and how to resize them? Do you know how to display them?

Comment: For all of these there's a neat & tidy way to do it (the Magento way) or you can just all of the logic inside one single file -- bad, because there's no division of concerns.

Comment: If you find a question in the list above to which you don't know the answer -- you should do a bit of research ([Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) has a lot of stuff), play around and try it yourself and if it doesn't work then  ask a separate question on StackOverflow for each particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the master category "Apple" output to "Static block and products" under the category settings->tab "Display settings"->option "Display mode".

After that, you create a static CMS block with contents like this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="8" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Which should output the product listing for category 8 inside the CMS block. No coding needed. This is untested, but should work unless I screwed up the syntax for the CMS block.