# Magento - Filter Product Collection by BOTH multiple catgeories

Tags: magento, collections, filter, categories

In my magento store i need to filter my product collection by 2 categories.

I have searched online and found ways of doing this (see existing code below) but they filter multiple categories using an `OR` condition – is there any way to do this with an `AND` condition so the products have to be found in BOTH categories not just any of them?

I am currently using the code below:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
        array('finset' => '26'),
        array('finset' => '63'))
    )
    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');

    foreach($_productCollection as $_product){
        echo $_product->getName()."<br/>";
    };
```

My product/category setup is:

products:

```
category 1 (ID 26)
category 2 (ID 63)

product A - found in category 1
product B - found in category 1 & 2
product C - found in category 1 & 2
```

So my current code below would output all 3 products where as i want it to only show products B and C

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento filter product collection by multiple categories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468059/magento-filter-product-collection-by-multiple-categories)

Comment: Thanks but had tried all the suggestions in the link without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up filtering by just the 1 category, and then on the for each output checking if the product id is present in the 2nd category. Not ideal but does the job for now

```
$_filter = 26;

foreach($_productCollection as $_product){
    $cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
    if (in_array($_filter, $cats)):
        ....
    endif; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried applying the filters sequentially?

So replace this:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
    array('finset' => '26'),
    array('finset' => '63'))
)
```

With this:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(array('finset' => '26')))
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(array('finset' => '63')))
```

This is generally how Magento likes to apply AND filters to collections.